# Impossible to do a fs.write operation in some folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to create a database-like structure using json files as a storage system, and I have made a method in an utilitarian class to help with it, however I am unable to use it depending on the path of the place I want to write at.

I have established that the method works, but only in some paths, I  know the path is correct everytime, but some pathes just leave the program hanging; yielding no error and not even the debug logs I have left in.

Here is the method that saves an object at a chosen path.

```
    /*
    ** Saves `file` object into `path`.
    ** Will attempt backup first, and may reload a backup on errors
    */
    save: function(path, file) {
        this.backup(path, file, () => {
            FS.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(file), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    this.log(err, this.LogTypes.ERROR);
                    this.log(`Something wrong happened, FS.writeFile operation on '${path}' failed!`, this.LogTypes.ERROR);
                    if (FS.existsSync(`${path}.bak`)) {
                        this.log(`Reverting '${path}' to backup!`, this.LogTypes.DATABASE);
                        FS.copyFile(`${path}.bak`, `${path}`, (err) => {
                            if (err) {
                                this.log(err, this.LogTypes.ERROR);
                                this.log(`Unable to restore backup from '${path}.bak'! '${path} may have been corrupted or destroyed!'`, this.LogTypes.ERROR);
                            } else this.log(`'${path}' has been restored to the latest backup successfully.`, this.LogTypes.DATABASE);
                        });
                    } else this.log(`Backup for '${path}' was not found, cannot restore backup!\nPlease make sure that ${path} is not damaged, or is an operation-critical file, and restart the bot.`, this.LogTypes.ERROR);
                } else {
                    this.log(`'${path}' has been saved successfully!`, this.LogTypes.DATABASE);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

It's implementation in code is through the use of `Utils.save("path"; Object)`

Comment: Maybe some permission issues on those paths?

Comment: I do not think so, the problem is persistent even in administrator mode.

Comment: output all the paths that you are using maybe you can spot something that is missing? regarding the permission maybe admin even can not write to those paths?

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: And do the same paths have the same problems each time?  If so, what are those paths and how are they different from other paths (or files, for that matter).

Comment: I am certain those paths are valid, using the LTS version of Node. The only time I have successfully written to the paths was when calling that method from the root of the working directory